# Ignore driver.close when there is no newly opened windows

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'd like to use driver.close() on a newly opened windows but in this case i'm not sure if a pop up windows is gonna open up every time I click on an element so the idea is to tell selenium to ignore driver.close if there is no newly opened windows.
Thanks.

Comment: Any tries that you have given? Show the code please.

Comment: driver.switch_to.window (driver_handles [-1])                          driver.close ()

Comment: it works but when there is no new window open, it closes the main window. I just want it to ignore this command instead of closing the main one...

Comment: I tried it with:                                                    try:                                                                     except Exception:                                          pass                                                             but same result

Comment: You should track handles to do this.  There are two methods you can use.  getWindowHandle() returns the driver's current handle.  getWindowHandles() returns an array of all handles.  If the array is larger than you expect you can know that something "popped" up a window or tab.  Also be aware of "pupunders" which would change the current window/tab to another page while opening the current page in the new handle/tab/popup.  So store the handles for the current driver, and any you want to stay open... compare the handles in the array against those and close the one that doesn't match.

Comment: is there a way to ignore the command (it would be easier)
For example: if there is more than one window open switch and close it or else do nothing.

Comment: Yes, Ben's answer below covers that if you only ever want one tab/window open.  If you come across popunder's though you'll probably want to verify that the driver is in the correct window first.  (maybe checking the current url, or for the existence of a webelement that is expected..)  In the case of popunder the focus is changed to a window/tab that is not the window/tab that the driver is currently in.   You might want to switch to the new tab for that case, and then close the original.

Comment: @pcalkins, I'm not sure the popunder would be an issue because even though the focus can change for the end-user, the webdriver remains "attached" to the original window/tab unless `switchTo` is used, so I think my proposed solution would also cover that case.

Comment: Yep... but the rest of the procedures/actions might assume it's still on the original page.  Though I think in any case the DOM references would go stale so using a .get() afterwards might be mandatory for popunder.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention which language you were using so here how it's done in Javascript (it will be easy to translate to another language using the [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/)):

```js
const handles = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
if (handles.length > 1) await driver.switch_to.window(handles[-1]).close();
```

Note that the previous code snippet assumes that it is always the last opened window that should be closed and that there is only one window to close.

It could be a mistake in some cases, so here is a safer way to close all tabs/windows which are not the active one:

```js
const handles = await driver.getAllWindowHandles();
if (handles.length > 1) {
  const currentHandle = await driver.getWindowHandle();
  handles
    .filter((handle) => handle !== currentHandle)
    .map(async (handle) => {
      await driver.switchTo().window(handle);
      await driver.close();
    });
  // don't forget to switch back to the original window
  await driver.switchTo().window(currentHandle);
}
```

Comment: Great! You should validate the answer then :)

Comment: I don't know how to do that...

Comment: There is a button to mark the answer as accepted

Comment: I don't see it...